# if/else not working on subdomain

Tags: php, html

I don't know how to go about this, but I'd like my users to use `m.site_url.com` for the mobile version of the site. I have a CMS, and the mobile version of my main site is outside CMS folders. Once the user opens this URL, they are asked to login. The login has a following redirection upon form submit

```
<input type="hidden" name="mobileVersion" value="True">
<input type="hidden" name="redir" value="../mobile/crew_center.php" />
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="login" />
<input class="login-btn" type="submit" name="submit" value="Log In" />
```

`/mobile` is the folder for the `m` directory in the URL. When the user opens `m.site_url.com` (site_url.com as an example) the following if/else is ran in the index.php of this URL.

```
<?php include_once'/home/flyeurov/public_html/core/codon.config.php'; // This includes functions of a CMS for instance Auth::LoggedIn

if(Auth::LoggedIn())
{
    header("Location: crew_center.php");
} 
else
{
    header("Location: login.php");
}

?>
```

The above code works for the direct path, for example when the user is logged in, entering `site_url.com/mobile` will open crew_center.php page. However, when the user types in `m.site_url.com` it will always display login.php regardless of whether the user is logged in or not.

How can I get this statement to work on `m.site_url.com` subdomain?

Comment: What's the code of your codon.config.php ?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/BWcbddGG

Comment: Do you sure that Auth Class not depend on the site URL? I think it is a matter of Cookie, sub domain is regarded as different site! Does it after login with the sub domain rember the user as usual with the main domain?

Comment: Yes, the user is logged in on the main domain.

Comment: I know that, my question is: Does he login as usual if he perform logged in from the sub-domain i.e the conditional if else works fine?

Comment: this is probably because of the sub domain. eg: the browser creates the session cookie for site_url.com, but it does not apply to m.site_url.com (which upon logging in will create another cookie). Wherever the authentication happens, there should be a cookie domain setting. set it to *.site_url.com

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways you can try to get your Sessions work cross subdomain:

```
session_set_cookie_params(0, '/', '.your_url.com');
session_start();
```

is one of them.

or try this: [Sharing session data across domains with PHP](http://www.gonnalearn.com/2008/04/10/sharing-session-data-across-domains-with-php/)